# Subtraction of Big $O$'s

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

So we were asked to prove something in class, but I can't understand the following expression:

> What is $O(n^2)-O(n^2)$?

I understand big O notation, but what I don't understand is the subtraction of two big $O$'s. my first thought was that the sets are infinite but yet identical so the subtraction will be an empty set.

Please shed some light...

Comment: How is the subtraction defined? Are you using the formal definition of $O(n^2)$ as the set of all functions of order $n^2$? Or is $O(n^2)$ just informally defined as "some function of order $n^2$"?

Answer (score 8):

If $O(n^2)-O(n^2)$ is defined as the set of sequences $(z_n)$ such that there exists $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ with $x_n\in O(n^2)$, $y_n\in O(n^2)$, and, for all $k$, $z_k=x_k-y_k$, then $O(n^2)-O(n^2)=O(n^2)$, as readily seen by proving the double inclusion.

More generally, for every sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$, $O(x_n)-O(y_n)=O(z_n)$ with $z_n=|x_n|+|y_n|$ or, equivalently, with $z_n=\max\{|x_n|,|y_n|\}$.

Comment: how is the last two expression equivalent? they are obviously not

Comment: zn=max{|xn|,|yn|} is much better approx

Comment: @jamesblack Thanks for your enthusiasm. Perhaps, though, try to **read** what is written before posting nonsensical comments.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance...but i did read the whole thing and to my understanding max of the two is obviously bigger than the sum of the other two please correct me where ive been wrong

Comment: by better i meant that in a relative sense $O(n^2)−O(n^2)=O(n^2)$ and obviously the sum of x y can be >= O(2n^2) which is still O(n^2) but the max approx gives you O(n^2) insread of O(2n^2) so its better in a relative sense (if it n gets infinitely large then yes the two are the same)

Comment: @jamesblack As I already tried to indicate (but with little success, it seems), reviewing the basics of $O$ and $o$ would be a viable alternative to polluting the comment thread of this question. Indeed, $O(n^2)=O(2n^2)$ and this class is strictly completely rigorously equal to $O(7n^2)$. Likewise, $O(|x_n|+|y_n|)=O(\max\{|x_n|,|y_n|\})$, always, and completely rigorously.